# str accessor with string values

Tags: normalization

i want to normalize the string caracter in my dataframe df_engin_valide_dedup

```
for col in list(df_engin_valide_dedup):
    if df_engin_valide_dedup[col].dtype=='object':
        df_engin_valide_dedup[col] = (df_engin_valide_dedup[col].str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').str.decode('utf-8').str.upper().fillna('INCONNU'))
    else: 
        df_engin_valide_dedup[col]
```

and i get the message
`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

so when i remove the str i can another message :

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'normalize'`

i expect all caracter to be normalize, in upper case.

Comment: This site uses English. Please also see the edit help & some of the (literally) millions of other posts re formatting & general style. Please avoid social & meta content.  Read the site [help] before you start posting. Debug questions require a [mre].